# Three points in a metric space that satisfy the triangle inequality with equality, but are not collinear.

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, geodesic

I'm looking for three points $x,y,z$ in a metric space $X$ that satisfy the triangle inequality with equality, so
$$
\mathrm{d}(x,z)=\mathrm{d}(x,y)+\mathrm{d}(y,z),
$$
but are not collinear.

Three points $x,y,z$ are collinear if there is a continuous, distance-preserving mapping $ \gamma : I \to X $ with $x,y,z \in \gamma(I)$ and $ I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an interval.

I have no idea right now. Maybe someone has a tip?

Comment: Your question seems contradictory. If the distances add up in a strict equality, doesn't that imply that they are collinear?

Comment: In our lecture we proved that three different colinear points $x,y,z$ with $\mathrm{d}(x,z)\geq \mathrm{d}(x,y)$ and $\mathrm{d}(x,z)\geq \mathrm{d}(y,z)$ always satisfy $\mathrm{d}(x,z)=\mathrm{d}(x,y)+\mathrm{d}(y,z)$.

Comment: The converse statement is generally not said to be true.

Comment: So you're saying being collinear implies equality, but equality somehow does not imply being collinear?

Comment: At least that is the claim we are asked to show in our exercise.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor The relevant definition of collinearity is spelled out. The problem is definitely solvable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: A subspace of any given metric space keep all the same distances, but a lot of previously collinear points may be non-collinear.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\{0,1,2\}$, and define a metric $d$ on $X$ by setting $d(0,1)=d(1,2)=1$ and $d(0,2)=2$. (Of course $d(x,x)=0$ for all $x\in X$.)

Comment: I thought of this as modifying the discrete metric on a three-point set, but of course it can also be viewed as an extreme version of Arthur’s suggestion.